# WSL Docker環境でパスのマウントを行う

Tags: windows, docker, wsl, wsl-2

**解決したいこと**
Windows11 でWSL2を使用してDocker環境を構築し、Jupyternotbookを使えるようにすることでKaggleに参加しようと思っています。

ただ上記は実装できたのですが、データを取り入れるためにローカルドライブをマウントしようとしたところ、エラーとなってしまいできません。

どなたか解決方法を教えてください。

**実行環境**
windows11
WSL2
Docker for Windows
Container - Ubuntu 20.13 LTS

**発生している問題・エラー**

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /new.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

**該当するソースコード**

```
$ docker run -p 8888:8888 -v "//C://Users//username//OneDrive//デスクトップ//Kaggle Folder//Test":/new ubuntu
```

**自分で試したこと**
試したこと1:
絶対パスにして/を2つずつ付与した。

```
"//C://Users//username//OneDrive//デスクトップ//Kaggle Folder//Test"
```

試したこと2:
「"」をつけないとImageはlower caseにしてくださいというエラーになるので、つけた。

試したこと3:
Containerのフォルダパスの名前をbinとか、違う名前にしてみた。

どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Comment: `:/new` はどのような意図で付けていますか？ (この部分でエラーになっているように見えます)

Comment: ご確認ありがとうございます！
下記のパスの通り、docker imageにあるフォルダを指定していました。
そもそもdocker runする前にimageにあるフォルダを見る方法もよくわからなかったので、別のコンテナを作って確認しました。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46979108/in-jupyter-where-is-home-jovyan

Answer (score 1):

WSL 2 の Ubuntu などの上で `docker` コマンドを実行しているのであれば、パスは Ubuntu などで認識できる形式にすると良いです。

たとえば Windows 側のドライブ C は WSL 側では `/mnt/c` にマウントされているので、以下のようにすると実行できるでしょう。

```sh
docker run -p 8888:8888 -v "/mnt/c/Users/username/OneDrive/デスクトップ/Kaggle/Folder/Test:/new" ubuntu
```